# Numerical methods to solve a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I would like to ask for some pointers to what the available numerical methods are which I can use to obtain $\phi(x)$ for the second order differential equation

$\phi''(x) + v(x) \phi'(x) + u(x) \phi(x) = 0$

or

$\phi''(x) + v(x) \phi'(x) + u(x) \phi(x) = h(x)$
.

Comment: Boundary conditions?

Comment: Depends on what you need the function for. This is one dimensional, so a lot of methods are available. Finite difference schemes output table of values at grid points for the function (and its derivative if you transform this to a system of first order equations).

Comment: In any case, please describe your particular problem in detail

Comment: You transform the second order ODE into a system of first order which is the form that most numerical ODE solvers expect as input.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I ended up doing. I've used the Numerov method before for problems when the first derivative is missing. What I was really wondering if there was a specific method for these kind of problems as well, similar in spirit.